# What my PPI should be set at for others to download my photos?

Tags: resolution, megapixels, selling, rescaling

I sell my photos  on Etsy for others to buy and download and I'm trying to figure out what I should set my PPI at and if I should resample when I do it...it is all very confusing. I'm reading all different sort of opinions on the Web about it.

I tried not resampling and it made my images very small. So I don't know what to do.

Advice!!?

Comment: It doesn't matter. PPI makes no difference when digitally downloaded. Modern print applications ignore it and scale the image to fit the paper size. The only time PPI has *any* effect is if a photo is placed inside another document using a word processing or page setting type of application.